# Jersey with PathParams

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to pass `PathParams` in the `GET` requests to my webservice. Here is the Service core:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Produces
    public String getIntentClassIds() {
        return "this works fine";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{x}")
    @Produces
    public String getIntentClassById(@PathParam("x") String intentClassId) {
        return "This does not work";
    }       
}
```

My **web.xml** looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyService API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mypackagename</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyService API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I just call my service like this:

`localhost:8080/MyService` it returns `this works fine` as expected. But when I try passing parameters like this: `localhost:8080/MyService/pathParam` it throws a `404`. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try not to declare MyService in web.xml, just declare the jersy dispatcher,
and in the class declare your service:

**not tested**

```
@Path("/MyService")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Produces
    @path("getIntentClassIds")
    public String getIntentClassIds() {
        return "this works fine";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getIntentClassById/{x}")
    @Produces
    public String getIntentClassById(@PathParam("x") String intentClassId) {
        return "This does not work";
    }

}
```

web.xml should not have mapping to your service MyService:
should look like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyService API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mypackagename</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyService API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

have a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a slash here:

```
@Path("/{x}")
```

change this to:

```
@Path("{x}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `@Path("/")` at class level, I think you dont need at method level any more.

Which just makes it like

`localhost:8080/MyService/(/ -> this is at service class level)[If you keep another here ; I think it cannot parse]pathParam`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<url-pattern>/MyService/*</url-pattern>
```

in your `web.xml`.

The calling `URL` will be `/MyService/something/dosomemore`

And in your java file,

```
@Path("/something")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Produces
    public String getIntentClassIds() {
        return "this works fine";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/dosomemore")
    @Produces
    public String getIntentClassById(@PathParam("x") String intentClassId) {
        return "This does not work";
    }       
}
```